# Callback function of vscode.workspace.onDidCloseTextDocument is working at development but not after packaging to vsix

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my extension, I'm opening a local file using `vscode.workspace.openTextDocument` and then `vscode.window.showTextDocument` and `vscode.workspace.onDidCloseTextDocument` to close the file.

This seems to be working fine if run the extension using the code.

Now I have created the vsix file using vsce package. Here comes the tricky thing

Both `vscode.workspace.onDidOpenTextDocument` and `vscode.workspace.onDidSaveTextDocument` callbacks are called as expected. However
`vscode.workspace.onDidCloseTextDocument` callback is not called when I close the file in the UI.(I am facing this issue when the extension is installed.)

Am I missing anything?

Steps to Reproduce:

1) Open the file using `vscode.workspace.openTextDocument` and then `vscode.window.showTextDocument`.

2) Listen for events in `vscode.workspace.onDidCloseTextDocument`.

3) Close the file in the editor.

4) Check that `vscode.workspace.onDidCloseTextDocument` callback is not called as expected.

Code is present in this git repo https://github.com/akhilravuri1/hellovscode, please clone the code and create vsix package by typing `vsce package` command in the cmd. Install the extension using vsix file and select the hello world command then it will open a file but when you close it just closes but I expect a select option with YES or NO at command palette.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Check the dev tools console, there might be a stacktrace / error there.

Comment: Does it also happen when you copy the extension development directory to the VSC extension directory of the current user?

Comment: @rioV8 sorry to tag you. I have copied the code to C:\Users\rakhil\.vscode\extensions and tested it was working fine but when I package it then it doesn't work.

Comment: @Gama11 sorry to tag you. In the log, the close function is not called at all. Is there something that I  missed. If it is related to workspace then how it is opening the file but not closing the file.Any Ideas?

Comment: use `vsce ls` to see which files are packaged and see which files are missing compared to the full directory. you can also use 7-zip to open the vsix file

Comment: How can you possible get a vsix file. I get 2 major **ERROR**s I have to fix before it is willing to create a vsix and it reports an big **WARNING**

Comment: When I put the vscode.workspace.onDidCloseTextDocument() in context.subscriptions.push() It started detecting the file close but the problem is not able to retrive the data in the file. If I see the logs It's strange It is opening normal file but while closing the file name is .txt.git ```

THIS IS PATH_FILE c:\Users\rakhil\VSCode_DevOps\hellovscode\ddl1.txt

close call c:\Users\rakhil\VSCode_DevOps\hellovscode\ddl1.txt.git

THIS IS VALUE (EMPTY)  ```

Comment: @rioV8 can you paste the warnings that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your extension.

I get the OnClose-event when the **Welcome Screen** text editor closes and `ddl.txt` is loaded.

The docs say you should use the `vscode.window` on-events but they do not allow to monitor a document close.

Very strange that the OnClose-event is fired on language change (this happens). You can't tell if it is a language change or document close.

When I open the `ddl.txt` with `File > Open` and close it I get the OnClose-event.

I get the OnClose-event on all files opened with `File > Open`.

It looks like files opened with `vscode.workspace.openTextDocument` and `vscode.window.showTextDocument` do not fire an OnClose-event.

You should file a bug because these calls generate a normal `TextDocument`.

Comment: Thanks, @rioV8 I have raised an issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/79110 but no response. Can you please make a comment that you are also facing the same issue? so that they might look into it.

Comment: @akhil Wait a day and look for a responds

Comment: @akhil. Bug report is wrong. It is not even working during development for me.

Comment: it is not working for me also..let me check it and update you.